# Spotify Script runs in Thonny but not in terminal

Tags: terminal

I have a simple python code that connects to my Spotify-Account and selected device and plays the song I want.

In Thonny it works without any problems, but whenever I try to run it in the terminal I get many questions whether allowing cookies or not, like:

- accounts.spotify.com cookie: _asdfasdfasdf Allow? (Y/N/Always/neVer)

Although I allow every single cookie I get to a part I don't get any further:

[image]

I also get there whenever I answer with Always.

As I want to run the script every time the raspberry start, I need to fix this issue. Can you help me out?

Thank you in advance!

Code: (Source: https://github.com/talaexe/Spotify-RFID-Record-Player/tree/main)

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth


device_id= ""
client_id= ""
client_secret= ""

# Spotify Authentication
sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(client_id=client_id,
                                               client_secret=client_secret,
                                               redirect_uri="http://localhost:8080",
                                               scope="user-read-playback-state,user-modify-playback-state"))


# Transfer playback to the Raspberry Pi if music is playing on a different device
sp.transfer_playback(device_id=device_id, force_play=False)

# Play the spotify track at URI with ID 45vW6Apg3QwawKzBi03rgD (you can swap this for a diff song ID below)
sp.start_playback(device_id=device_id, context_uri='spotify:album:0JGOiO34nwfUdDrD612dOp')
```